# List, dictionary, and tuple values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

```
a=[{"a":30},{"c":("a","=","c")}]
```

I need values of `"c"`.

```
for x in a[1].values():
    for j in x:
        print(j, end=" ")
```

This is my solution but if you have any other short solution for this then tell me.

Comment: What's wrong with `a[1]['c']` or even `print(*(_ for _ in a[1]['c']))`?

Comment: What is the question? You're providing an example but does it do what you expect? If yes, why do you need another solution? If not, what do you expect? If I take your actual question literally, the answer is: `"c"`. That's "the value of `"c"`".

Comment: For those like me who didn't know what the * was, look for "tuple unpacking", or other uses at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call

Answer (score 2):

You could simply say

```py
for element in a[1]['c']:
       print(element,end=" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
>>> print(' '.join(*a[1].values()))
a = c
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the values to be printed, you can unpack the tuple as arguments to `print`:

```
print(*a[1]['c'])
```

Comment: Most Pythonic answer of all for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The same result can be achieved with a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a=[{"a":30},{"c":("a","=","c")}]
>>> print(*(_ for _ in a[1]['c']))
a = c
>>>
```